# Where is the misc tab when you press n?

Tags: interface

When I press <kbd>N</kbd> , next to item, tool, and view should be misc right? It isn’t there for me but I need it for kinematics settings

Comment: In Blender 2.8x there isn't. What exactly are you trying to do and what particular settings are you looking for? Is this related to an add-on that should add its settings to that tab?

Comment: I was using a tutorial for a Spider-Man animation and the Spider-Man rig has settings that need to be changed through the rig main properties in the misc tab

Answer (score 1):

When you open up the Spider-man model it blocks a script for the rig, which Blender asks your permission to run or ignore. I enabled the script the second time running it and the Misc tab showed up for me.